# Update TableView after changing an Object | UISeachBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I programmed a Notebook app. I save all Object in an array and in the Core Data.
Now I implemented a UISearchBarController . The results of the SearchBar are saved in a different array the filteredarray. If I now click on one of the results it changes to the DetailView of the clicked Object. If I now edit the name of the note, and save , I get back to the past view and it changes it in the CoreData. When the view appears,the search bar is still active and the tableview will be build with my filteredarray and the Object I changed , has it's old name. But when I close the Search Bar , the name changes. Is it possible to manually close the search bar when I jump back to the main view?

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.searchDisplayController?.active = false
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this code answers the question?

Comment: @rfornal it's quite basic and set searchDisplayController as inactive, thus hiding it from the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable your search display controller when the view disappears (or appears). I don't know the method name by heart but it should be something like `.enabled` or `.active` or something similar.

That being said, I would do it in the `viewDidDisappear` so it's done when you leave the page (and ready for when you come back) and you don't have a flash when you come back to it (which you would have if you put it in the `viewDidAppear` method)

Answer (score 0):

`UISearchBarController` inherits from UIViewController, that means you can present and dismiss it at will from your main ViewController using these 2 methods.

```
    let searchController = UISearchController() // example

    self.presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil) // your main ViewController will present the SearchBarViewController

    searchController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) // your UISearchController() will dismiss itself
```

If you want to keep the `UISearchController` around and hide only the `UISearchBar` which inherits from UIView so you have a .hidden property you can use: `searchController.searchBar.hidden = true`

also as I understand from your question, your issue is that the searchBar is still active showing previous search results and you can force it to become inactive changing the following property: `searchController.active = false` dismissing the search interface but keeping the `UISearchController` and its `UISearchBar` around for the user to use it again if they choose to click in the search field.

Comment: please add a little description

Comment: Just did, hope you're happy with the details now.